# 2018-07-11 23:52:13.710 format to %y-%m-%d(2018-07-11) by pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
1       2018-07-11 23:52:13.710
2       2016-09-02 13:52:00.163
3       2018-01-10 23:28:00.187
4       2017-09-11 22:21:24.487
5       2017-01-06 09:55:01.110
```

I have a series `a` as above which its' dtype is string. I want to convert it to this format(%y-%m-%d).

`pd.to_datetime(df['a'],format='%Y-%m-%d)` could not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit or specify parameter `format` and then use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) - output are python objects `date`s:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['a']).dt.date
#with format parameter
#s = pd.to_datetime(df['a'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.date
print (s)
1    2018-07-11
2    2016-09-02
3    2018-01-10
4    2017-09-11
5    2017-01-06
Name: a, dtype: object

print (s.values[:3])
[datetime.date(2018, 7, 11) datetime.date(2016, 9, 2)
 datetime.date(2018, 1, 10)]
```

---

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) - output are datetimes with no times:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['a']).dt.floor('d')
#with format parameter
#s = pd.to_datetime(df['a'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('d')
print (s)
1   2018-07-11
2   2016-09-02
3   2018-01-10
4   2017-09-11
5   2017-01-06
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Last if need strings of datetimes in custom format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['a']).dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
#with format parameter
#s = pd.to_datetime(df['a'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d')
print (s)
1    18-07-11
2    16-09-02
3    18-01-10
4    17-09-11
5    17-01-06
Name: a, dtype: object

print (s.values[:3])
['18-07-11' '16-09-02' '18-01-10']
```